# To show the inequality about $\mathcal L^1$ function.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lebesgue-integral

I want to see the statement below.

---

For $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mathbb R)$,$a\in\mathbb R,t>0$, $$\frac{1}{2t}\int_{a-t}^{a+t}|f(x)-f(a)|dx\leqq\sup_{|x-a|\leqq t}|f(x)-f(a)|.$$

---

My book says that this is shown easily by this proposition:

For measure space $(X,\mathcal S,\mu)$, $A\in\mathcal S$, $f:X\to[-\infty,\infty]$, if $\int_A fd\mu$ is defined, then $$\left|\int_A fd\mu\right|\leqq\mu(A)\sup_{x\in A}|f(x)|.$$

From this proposition, I have
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{a-t}^{a+t}f(x)-f(a) dx\right|
&=\left|\int_{[a-t,a+t]}f(x)-f(a) dx\right|\\
&\leqq m([a-t,a+t])\sup_{x\in[a-t,a+t]}|f(x)-f(a)|\\
&=2t\sup_{|x-a|\leqq t}|f(x)-f(a)|
\end{align}
,where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

And I get $\frac{1}{2t}\left|\int_{a-t}^{a+t}f(x)-f(a) dx\right|\leqq\sup_{|x-a|\leqq t}|f(x)-f(a)|.$

But this is a bit different from what I want to show:$\frac{1}{2t}\int_{a-t}^{a+t}|f(x)-f(a)|dx\leqq\sup_{|x-a|\leqq t}|f(x)-f(a)|.$

How can I derive this inequality ? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the triangle inequality first and apply the proposition with $|f(x)-f(a)|$ instead of $f(x)-f(a)$.